# .Net - Set a Setting in Settings.settings file to null

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

**Question**

Is it possible to override the value of a settings created in a settings file (Settings.settings) to be *null* in a app.config or web.config?

**Scenario**

I have a project (`SO.Example`) that has a Settings.setting file that defines a setting `SetMeToNull`:

[image: Screenshot of Settings.setting]

I have another project (`SO.Example.Web`) that uses `SO.Example`.  I would like to set `SetMeToNull` to null in the `So.Exmaple.Web`'s web.config:

```
   <SO.Example.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="SetMeToNull" serializeAs="String">
            <value>[[NULL]]</value>
        </setting>
    </SO.Example.Properties.Settings>
```

Obviously there are ways to work around this if it's not possible, but it would be convenient if it was possible.

**Justification**

This may seam like an odd requirement when in most cases an empty string could comfortably sit in for a null string.  At the moment, however, I'm faced with a case where a null string does not have the same meaning as an empty string.  For the sake of the argument, let's just say `SO.Example` is a 3rd party library and I have no control over it.  (Ie refactoring it would take more time than it's worth).

Comment: Question: Does it makes any sense to store a null value inside a settings file? If so, can it be replaced with an empty string?

Comment: @Oscar - Excellent pondering.  In some edge cases it can make sense to store null.  I've updated the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the settings file with the XML editor instead of the default editor and set it manually to:

```
 <Setting Name="Setting" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)"></Value>
 </Setting>
```

But I wonder if it makes any sense to have a setting set to null..

Comment: This is interesting.  So this will set it the value to null in `SO.Example`.  But what happens if `SO.Example` sets a value and I need to overwrite it in `SO.Example.Web`?

Comment: This technique did not work to override the value in the `web.config`.  Neither did setting the value to `<value />`.

Comment: @PhilipPittle This was not part of your original question, you just asked how to set it to null. However, you can modify the webconfig file by hand, or otherwise there is a full bloom API, mainly trough System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager class

Comment: Interesting to know.  That might be a bit too much effort for my scenario as I'm using a build server, so wiring in code execution might be difficult. But thanks for sharing this!