# How to create a Nullable DateTime in Settings?

Tags: c#

I need to create a `System.DateTime` in the settings of my application, now if the field isn't valorized I get this date:

```
01/01/0001 00:00:00
```

trying to access as: `Properties.Settings.Default.LastUpdated;`

I need to compare the value and check if is null. Now the problem is that if the date isn't setted I'll get the value above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Settings.Settings` doesn't support null - perhaps add additional property to indicate that it is null.

Comment: Maybe this link should be able to help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622276/net-set-a-setting-in-settings-settings-file-to-null

Comment: So I can manage this only via code?

Comment: I believe so. I never actually seen a null value in the Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime is a struct, so it is a value type not a reference type.
As such, it is not nullable.

You may use DateTime.MinValue instead.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.LastUpdated==DateTime.MinValue)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are never going to use that date than you can put it in a global constant variable and name that variable DateNull. After that just compare them. 
You can even use nullable types since DateTime is value type so you can have

```
DateTime? myDate;
```

If you make a condition like this

```
if(myDate == null)
```

it would evaluate to true.